# Why does Reference.cs (WCF Service Reference) get generated with the wrong method signature

Tags: c#, wcf

The error I'm getting is:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Tuple[]' to 'Tester.CommService.TupleOfstringSqlDbTypeanyTypep2GUUk_Sk[]'

From the following:

```
CommService.CommServiceClient client = new CommService.CommServiceClient();
Tuple<string, System.Data.SqlDbType, object>[] parameters = new Tuple<string, System.Data.SqlDbType, object>[] { 
    new Tuple<string, System.Data.SqlDbType, object>(
        paramName, 
        System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 
        projectid)};
client.Open();
string myValue = client.getScalar(procName, parameters);
client.Close();
```

The actual method signature is:

```
string getScalar(string procedure, IEnumerable<Tuple<string, SqlDbType, object>> parameters);
```

I've tried deleting the service reference and re-adding it.

I've also tried configuring the service reference, unchecking the 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies' option, then updating the service reference.

I've tried using the following, but it also generates the same error.

```
CommService.ICommService service = new CommService.CommServiceClient();
CommService.getScalarRequest request = new CommService.getScalarRequest(procName, parameters);
service.getScalar(request);
```

I've noticed that the Reference.cs also contains the following:

```
// CODEGEN: Parameter 'getScalarResult' requires additional schema information that cannot be captured using the parameter mode. The specific attribute is 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute'.
```

I've used this service reference and the same method in other projects without issue.

Comment: WCF is interoperable by default, and therefore, you would be well advised *not* to use .NET specific types like `Tuple` ....

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a service reference, you have the option to reuse types in referenced assemblies. Check that this option is enabled.

Right click the service reference, select **Configure Service Reference...**, check **Reuse types in referenced assemblies** and select **Reuse types in all referenced assemblies**, then click **OK**.

Also, @marc_s's comment is correct - you should probably avoid built-in .NET types (that aren't native XML types) - but only if you intend the service to be interoperable (i.e. available to non-WCF clients).

Comment: I have attempted this both with the reuse types in referenced assemblies checked and reuse types in all referenced assemblies selected. The same issue persists.